# Taanis bechorim when unable to attend a siyum

Tags: passover, fast-days, siyum

This year, due to coronavirus related isolation measures, the probability is that a bechor would be unable to attend an actual siyum on erev pesach.

Can a bechor see a siyum online or must he fast on erev pesach?

Comment: He should make a siyum himself. Two weeks is plenty of time to learn something.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes Horayos is 14 dapim. However, I would suggest that the question should be asked anyway so that the answers are available for those who need it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Maseches Horayos has 14 dapim. It will be part of the daf yomi cycle this coming Elul 10 - 22 so it is regarded as valid for a siyum. One is thus able to use it for the siyum this year if one can complete it, treating it as a daf yomi. It is part of Art Scroll Talmud volume 54.

Rabbi Hershel Schechter sent out an [answer](http://www.torahweb.org/torah/docs/rsch/RavSchachter-Corona-1-Mar-24-2020.pdf) (with translation)

> ראיתי בתשו' הרב הנקין ז"ל (גבורות אליהו חאו"ח סי' קמ"ג) שכתב שמנהג
>   הבכורים להתענות לא קיים בזמנינו שכבר נהגו שהכל משתתפים בסיום מסכתא ולא
>   מתענים. ואילו היה חיוב להתענות (אפילו מטעם מנהג) לא היה הסיום שעושים
>   אצלנו מספיק להתיר אכילה, הואיל ואין עושים באמת סעודת מצוה, אלא רק מקצת
>   מזונות ומיץ תפוזים וכדומה. ע"כ מן הנכון לפדות התענית בצדקה עכ"ד.
>   וכמדומה לי שבשנים כתקונם הרבה טסים להוריהם על פסח ויהא במטוס (או בשדה
>   התעופה) בבקר בי"ד ניסן, וכבר נהגו להשתתף דרך הטלפון בסיום, וככה יעשו
>   אף בשנה זו.
>
> Regarding the Fast of the Firstborn, Rabbi Yosef Eliyahu Henkin wrote
>   that in our time the custom of firstborn sons fasting no longer exists
>   because everyone participates in a siyum. There is clearly no mandate
>   to fast since we find people don’t participate in an actual Seudas
>   Mitzvah and instead, following the siyum, they simply partake of some
>   juice and cookies. Therefore, Rabbi Henkin felt it was proper to give
>   tzedakah to take the place of the custom of fasting. In past years
>   those people who are traveling on Erev Pesach have participated in a
>   siyum over the phone or internet. The same practice can be relied upon
>   this year when we are not gathering together because of the
>   Coronavirus.

Comment: Note that as a result of the coronavirus there are those who say we cannot fast on erev Pesach for health reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Over the phone (live stream equivalent) is fine *bshaas hadchak* according to Rav Shlomo Zalmen Auerbach.

[image]

Comment: Is neglecting to study in advance for your own siyum when you have had weeks notice that you won't be able to attend someone else's considered Oneis?

Comment: The Ones is that one cannot join in person ,so the phone works in this instance ,you're focused on the learning I am focusing on the joining part

Comment: I'm not focusing on any one part. This is techilato bpshia vsofo boneis which may not count. You haven't given any reason to think that someone who could learn and has advance notice can plan to rely on this.

Comment: I am not understanding your reasoning, who said this bachur couldn't learn either,all it says that he couldn't join the siyum,if anything its mashma the joining is the ones,and we dont care whether he can learn or not on his own

Comment: mistama the case by rsza was he got stuck by surprise on erev pesach morning, not that he had two weeks notice to plan

Comment: What is the full citation for that source @sam